# Unity AddForce to game object

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

how can i do AddForce function from this scheme [CLICK](http://mgc-friends.com/how_to.png), im make game like paper toss, am need to add AddForce to object from Angel of touches. I have two cordinates in BEGIN phase and ENDED phase.How can i pull the ball from touch trajectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by calculating the vector for the ball based off your start and end positions. Subtract the start position from the end position and you will get a vector for the direction and distance of your touch swipe. Then, you can pass that vector into AddForce, along with whatever [Force.mode](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html), which will push the ball along your swipe path.